# Create Price Range in mongo with aggregation pipeline with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Wan't create Price range Using mongodb aggregation pipeline..
while using elastic search or solr we can directly get price filter range value... How can i create price range according to my products price, if there is no product in that range then don't create that range...

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5657412ddb70397479575d1d"),"price" : 1200
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5657412ddb70397479575d1d"),"price" : 200
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5657412ddb70397479575d1d"),"price" : 2000
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5657412ddb70397479575d1d"),"price" : 2020
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5657412ddb70397479575d1d"),"price" : 100
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5657412ddb70397479575d1d"),"price" : 3500
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5657412ddb70397479575d1d"),"price" : 3900
}
```

From above i have to create price range as par product price like filter available in flipkart OR myntra using Mongo aggregation...

```
[
        {
            range : '100-200',
            count : 2
        },
        {
            range : '1200-2020',
            count : 3
        },
        {
            range : '3500-3900',
            count : 2
        }

]
```

Answer (score 1):

Within the **[aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/)** pipeline, you can take advantage of the [**`$cond`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond) operator in the [**`$project`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) stage to create an extra field that denotes the range the price falls in, and then use the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** step to get the counts:

```
var pipeline = [    
    {
        "$project": {
            "price": 1,
            "range": {
                "$cond": [ 
                    {
                        "$and": [
                            { "$gte": ["$price", 100] },
                            { "$lte": ["$price", 200] }
                        ]
                    }, 
                    "100-200", 
                    {
                        "$cond": [ 
                            {
                                "$and": [
                                    { "$gte": ["$price", 1200] },
                                    { "$lte": ["$price", 2020] }
                                ]
                            }, 
                            "1200-2020", "2021-above" 
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    { 
        "$group": { 
            "_id": "$range",             
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }  
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,             
            "range": "$_id",
            "count": 1

        }
    }
];

collection.aggregate(pipeline, function (err, result){
     if (err) {/* Handle err */};
     console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
});
```

Comment: but want to decide that rage like here we can added manually min price and max price but i want to automated it

Comment: @AsheshKhatri Sorry I'm failing to understand your requirements here. I've tried to follow the example you gave in your question and produced the desired result using the pipeline above but what you are trying to do is honestly not clear without a solid [minimum verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i want to auto calculate rage of product price using query... I have product collection from that i have to calculate product price range.. like we have price range in e-commerce website @chridam

Comment: can u help me to auto calculate range of products using mongodb... @chridam

Comment: @AsheshKhatri I would really love to help but your example is not quite clear, I'm just failing to understand what you are trying to achieve. Can you please edit your question to clarify things a little bit, getting some guidelines from [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Currently you just want to auto calculate range of products, what range of products? Give a solid example with some sample documents that have the product name, price etc and the sort of result you are expecting from that sample collection.

Comment: At initial don't know the range of product price, after getting data want to create price rage, like in elastic search using facet query we get price range auto calculated with count@chridam